# Blank page on node.js passport facebook redirect on mobile

Tags: node.js, facebook, mobile, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I'm building a webservice based on node.js, I used passport authentication with the following setup:
on calling authentication:

```
clientID: "AAAA",
clientSecret: "BBBB",
callbackURL = "http://CCCC/facebook/loggedin";

app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', {scope : ['email', 'publish_actions', 'rsvp_event']}, {display: ['touch']}));
```

Everything works perfectly fine via chrome on my desktop pc and I get redirected with all the parameters
However, when trying to do the exact same thing on my ipad/android phone, the browser will leave me hanging in:

```
https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?redirect_uri=http%4a%2F%2FCCCC%2Ffacebook%2Floggedin&scope=email%2Cpublish_actions%2Crsvp_event&response_type=code&type=web_server&client_id=AAAA
```

with a completely blank page...

Has anyone tackled that?

**EDIT** :when i force my browser to be on desktop mode it will show the page as supposed..why would it work for the desktop but not the mobile?

**EDIT** :seems like a mobile problem with the browser